# What is the best way to create a Numbered RichtextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

The goal is to add a column of paragraph numbers to a RichTextBox (the numbers show the index of paragraphs in that richtextbox.Document.Blocks). Currently, I use this block of code in LayoutUpdated event of the RichTextBox:

```
bool _added=false
void onLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!_added)
   {
      _added= true;
      scv = Helper.GetFind.FindChild<ScrollViewer>(this, null);
      if (scv != null)
      {
         FrameworkElement  documentView = scv.Content as FrameworkElement;
         scv.ClearValue(ScrollViewer.ContentProperty);
         Grid grid= new Grid();
```

... I will talk about what I have added here...

```
         scv.Content = grid;
         UpdateLayout();
      }
   }
}
```

In the **grid**, I add two columns, the first one is a StackPanel and the second one is the **documentView**. For each paragraph I add a TextBlock to the StackPanel.Children and I set the height of each textBlock by using Paragraph.ElementStart.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward) methods and the Top & Bottom Properties of the returned *Rect*(s).

Everything is fine and when there are less than 500 paragraphs, the numbering updates quickly, But as the text gets larger, it gets slower. How can I make it more efficient? Should I use a Canvas instead of a StackPanel? Or is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the procedure I mensioned in the question and then `Dispacher.BeginInvoke(...)` method. I set `DispatcherPriority` to `ApplicationIdle`. I call it when Width chaneges or new `Paragraph` is added. Sth like this:

```
 _updateIfWidthChangedDispacherO= _ownerTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            updateIfWidthChanged();
        }),
        DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView GridView.  Support virtualiztion.   I use textblock for each line in some very large document and works great.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going to try it. but I do not know if using GetCharacterRect(...) method is a good way to get a paragraph height. I mean is there any better way?

Comment: I am not familiar with GetCharacterRect