# How to insert a paragraph's index beside it in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

The title explains everything. I want the user to know the index of the paragraph, he is editing.

Comment: I could not find any proper answer. I tried adding an InlineUIContainer at the beginning of the paragraph, but it is not what i want. I like it to be outside the text area.

Comment: Have you considered a GridView with each paragraph actually coming from a List.

Answer (score 0):

Put that information in a tooltip on the current run of the paragraph. For example my Richtextbox is setup like this:

```
<RichTextBox Name="rEdit"
             TextChanged="rEdit_TextChanged"
             IsDocumentEnabled="True">
```

Then on the TextChanged I setup a tooltip which gives me a total number of words in the paragarph which is shown when I hover over the paragraph:

```
 private void rEdit_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {

      if (rEdit.Selection != null)
      {
         var startpos = rEdit.Selection.Start;

         if (startpos != null)
         {
            var run = startpos.Parent as Run;

            if (run != null)
            {
               int count = 0;

               if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(run.Text) == false)
                  count = run.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();

               run.ToolTip = new Run("Words: " + count);
            }
         }
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `onLayoutUpdated()` event. See this link: [What is the best way to create a Numbered RichtextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334306/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-numbered-richtextbox). Of course the link does not explain everything. e.g. you should handle onMouseScroll event to.